# Can't see folder names in git, only .DS_Store

Tags: git, directory, init

I'm new to Git, so:

1. On my SSD drive I create a folder 'Repo' with two subfolders 'Master_1' and 'Master_2' and two files 'master_1.txt' and 'master_2.txt'
2. I go to that folder and execute *git init*
3. However, when I execute *git status*, I expect to see

Master_1/

Master_2/

master_1.txt

master_2.txt

but what I see in fact is

[image]

Why does it show .DS_Store and where are my two folders? I'm using Mac OS.

Comment: Git doesn't track empty folders, add a file inside them, also use a gitignore to ignore the .DS_Store file.

Comment: Please include the output of `ls` in that folder. And post the terminal text as text, not screenshots. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors